# Calling indexer.search_transactions with a group ID (Algorand)

Tags: python, algorand

Can I call indexer.search_transactions with a group id? Or otherwise, search for multiple transactions by group id.

The Python SDK doesn't like the group id format: `algosdk.error.IndexerHTTPError: invalid input: unable to parse base32 digest data 'txid': illegal base32 data at input byte 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot search by group ID.

You would want to search by txid, find the block it's in, and find the group ID, then fetch that block and identify all transactions that contain the same group ID.